# "ImportError: No module named pyRserve" when running AWS Glue job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

When I run my Glue job in which I try to import the pyRserve python module (pure Python), I'm getting this error:

```
LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time:Sun Jan 21 12:27:32 +0000 2018
LogLength:206
Log Contents:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script_2018-01-21-12-27-05.py", line 8, in <module>
import pyRserve
ImportError: No module named pyRserve
End of LogType:stdout
```

Here are details about my job:

```
$ aws glue get-job --job-name test_trunc
{
    "Job": {
        "Name": "test_trunc",
        "Role": "arn:aws:iam::#CLIPPED#:role/AWSGlueServiceRoleDefault",
        "CreatedOn": 1516192543.117,
        "LastModifiedOn": 1516537317.889,
        "ExecutionProperty": {
            "MaxConcurrentRuns": 1
        },
        "Command": {
            "Name": "glueetl",
            "ScriptLocation": "s3://#CLIPPED#/gluescripts/test_trunc"
        },
        "DefaultArguments": {
            "--TempDir": "s3://#CLIPPED#/jobs/test_trunc/scripts",
            "--extra-py-files": "s3://#CLIPPED#/jobs/test_trunc/python-libs/pyRserve.zip",
            "--job-bookmark-option": "job-bookmark-disable",
            "--job-language": "python"
        },
        "Connections": {
            "Connections": [
                "redshift"
            ]
        },
        "MaxRetries": 0,
        "AllocatedCapacity": 10
    }
}
```

Here is the script I'm running:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import pprint
import pyRserve
```

Here is the complete log:

https://gist.github.com/mattazend/b611d0232d94ade4bc4c16bcb79f73a8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to AWS Glue Documentation:
>
> Only pure Python libraries can be used. Libraries that rely on C
>   extensions, such as the pandas Python Data Analysis Library, are not
>   yet supported.

I think it wouldn't work even if we upload the python library as a zip file, if the library you are using has a dependency for C extensions.  I had tried using Pandas, Holidays, etc the same way you have tried, and on contacting AWS Support, they mentioned it is in their to do list (support for these python libaries), but no ETA as of now.

**@Ishwr:** According to this link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyRserve/0.9.1, pyRserve requires Numpy package as a pre-requisite for installation, and if numpy is not found in the installed libraries list, pyRserve first installs numpy before proceeding to pyRserve.

Since numpy is not supported by Glue, I believe due to this reason, pyRserve is either not installed from the zip file, or its not recognized/considered for the job and hence the ImportError.

> pyRserve has been written by Ralph Heinkel (www.ralph-heinkel.com) and
>   is released under MIT license.
>
> Quick Installation Make sure that Numpy is installed (version 1.4.x or
>   higher).
>
> Then from your unix/windows command line run:
>
> pip pyRserve For manual installation download the tar.gz or zip
>   package. After unpacking, cd into the pyRserve directory and run
>   python setup.py install from the command line.
>
> Actually pip pyRserve should install numpy if it is missing.

Hope am correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used a zip file in S3 for the library you are trying to import, as advised [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html)?

Comment: It doesn't work, and AWS Support have confirmed on this, that only pure python libaries/packages are supported by Glue currently, and any packages relying on C extensions are not supported.  ImportError is due to the reason, glue couldn't recognize the PyServe library.

Comment: @YuvaKumar he says in the question that it's a pure Python module.

Comment: @Isrwr, please see my updated answer, with pyRserve pre-requisites added to the answer